# Split a table by case by in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi guys I Have a data like this

[image]

My query is like this

```
SELECT Level_6 as Model, CarSegmentName_Short as Car_Type,
   b.CarVariant_Name,
    max(unit_priceOTR)  as OTR_Highest_Price,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY max(unit_priceOTR) DESC) Ranking
  from edw.[eview].[TB_R_CARPRICEOTR_APM] a
  join edw.[eview].[TB_M_CARVARIANT] b
    on a.CarVariant_Code = b.CarVariant_Code
     where   
    DT = '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000' and CarSegmentName_Short = 'S/D Lux Sport'
    group by Level_6,CarVariant_Name,CarSegmentName_Short
```

Basically, I want to split the *Model* table part into two tables the first table have highest OTR PRICE for **TOYOTA** and the second table have highest OTR price for **non-TOYOTA** both tables only contained one row (the top 1 model)

I think that this problem could be solved using sub query and the use of case when but I am still new to SQL so I got stuck for later queries

Final result that I intended should be like below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0C0b.jpg)

Comment: **Consumable** sample data (not an image) and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Pictures of data, no DDL, an unrelated query that refers to tables we haven't been introduced to, and no explanation of what about the result is displeasing to you? It makes helping harder than it ought to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT v.model_split, Level_6 as Model, CarSegmentName_Short as Car_Type,
       b.CarVariant_Name, max(unit_priceOTR)  as OTR_Highest_Price,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by v.model_split ORDER BY max(unit_priceOTR) DESC) Ranking
from edw.[eview].[TB_R_CARPRICEOTR_APM] a
     cross apply (values (case when Model like 'TOYOTA%' then 'Toyota' else 'Non-Toyota' end)) v(model_split)
     join edw.[eview].[TB_M_CARVARIANT] b on a.CarVariant_Code = b.CarVariant_Code
where DT = '2019-12-01 00:00:00.000' 
      and CarSegmentName_Short = 'S/D Lux Sport'
group by v.model_split, Level_6,CarVariant_Name, CarSegmentName_Short;
```